# Subquery to Count Date - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on database on MYSQL , i'm trying to make a query to get no of visits/month depend on below data :

[image]

as you can see there are repeated dates and in same time repeated fleet_codes

this my query :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(date_of_visit)) AS "no_of_visits", MONTHNAME(date_of_visit) AS 'Month' 
FROM vehicle_tyre_parameters
WHERE YEAR(date_of_visit) = YEAR(curdate()) AND fleet_code IN (SELECT DISTINCT(fleet_code) FROM vehicle_tyre_parameters WHERE fleet_code !="" )
GROUP BY Month,fleet_code,date_of_visit
ORDER BY FIELD(Month,'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','Septembre','October','November','December')
```

That what i got :

[image]

but what i need to get like that :
[image]

Appreciate your support to solve that issue .
Thanks

Comment: Why not just `GROUP BY Month`?

Comment: ACTUALLY I tried it , but it doesn't give me accurate numbers , as i have repeated dates and repeated count for example in January supposed to have 4 visits , when i use group by month i got 3 as it excludes FC-2 in same date of FC-1 (1/1/2021) , That's why i'm using group month and fleet_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do two things in your query.  You are trying to de-duplicate you data, and you are trying to summarize your data.  In order to solve this, you should think of those as two separate problems, and solve each one before you try to combine them.

De-duplicating your data is this simple

```
SELECT DISTINCT Month, fleet_code, date_of_visit
FROM vehicle_tyre_parameters
```

Your filter criteria is more complicated than it needs to be. The criteria:

```
WHERE fleet_code IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(fleet_code) 
    FROM vehicle_tyre_parameters 
    WHERE fleet_code !="" 
)
```

Is equivalent to

```
WHERE fleet_code !=""
```

So your de-duplication query becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Month, fleet_code, date_of_visit
FROM vehicle_tyre_parameters
WHERE YEAR(date_of_visit) = YEAR(curdate()) and fleet_code !=""
```

Now you can summarize the results of this query.  I prefer to use Common Table Expressions instead of subqueries to call one query from another because I think it is easier to read.  Your mileage may vary.

```
WITH dedup_results AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Month, fleet_code, date_of_visit
    FROM vehicle_tyre_parameters
    WHERE YEAR(date_of_visit) = YEAR(curdate()) and fleet_code !=""
)
SELECT COUNT(date_of_visit) AS no_of_visits, MONTHNAME(date_of_visit) AS Month
FROM dedup_results
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_of_visit)
ORDER BY MONTH(date_of_visit)
```

Doing both a SELECT DISTINCT and a GROUP BY is basically equivalent to doing two GROUP BY's.  Because you need both, there is no way to avoid using either a CTE or a subquery in this case.

** EDIT **

As I think about this more I remembered that COUNT(DISTINCT) can take more than one column as an argument.  So you can combine these two queries into one like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fleet_code, date_of_visit) AS no_of_visits, MONTHNAME(date_of_visit) AS Month
FROM vehicle_tyre_parameters
WHERE YEAR(date_of_visit) = YEAR(curdate()) and fleet_code !=""
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_of_visit)
ORDER BY MONTH(date_of_visit)
```

Comment: perfect . Thanks for your help and honestly , "Common Table Expression " is new for me but it seems it'll solve many many issues in near future for me. Appreciate it

Comment: Regarding last update about combining 2 queries in just one ; i got an error > 1146 - Table 'fleet.dedup_results' doesn't exist

Comment: This is the danger of copy-paste coding.  the from clause should have been "vehicle_tyre_parameters".  I have edited the post. While this does allow you to combine two queries into one, it isn't any more efficient, and, in my opinion, it's harder to read.  I still think the original answer is the better way to go, but if you want to minimize lines of code, the edit will do that.